Connecting to SQL Server named instance using ODBC fails
I have been writing a few python scripts using pyodbc.  So far, its been fine...until I tried this server thats using a named instance.  Windows 10 workstation to Windows 2019 server and SQL 2019
connStr = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=MyServerHere\\InstanceName;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;' 
print(connStr)
conn = odbc.connect(connStr)

This fails
However:
I can connect with SSMS from my workstation, as Im a local admin on the server Im connecting to
I can not create a system or user DSN using the ODBC Driver 17 from my PC.  When I get to the end of configuring it and try to test, I get a very similar error as when using Python. 
I see nothing in the SQL logs
tcp/ip and named pipes are both enabled in sql config manager.
What can I check?
[ update] 
After stumbling around for a while, I was able to create a system dsn (as a test of odbc) by changing the client settings to use named pipes.  So now I need to figure out why this sever is trying to force named pipes with connections rather than tcp/ip.
however, to use named pipes with pyodbc, I just changed my server name to use np: in front and it worked.
eg.
connStr = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=np:MyServerHere\\InstanceName;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;' 

